# On button click, I m adding an object (through struts 2) in a Database. But it is not reflecting at the same time

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, object, struts

On a button click, I am adding an object using struts 2 actions and that action is redirected to the same page on which retrieval of the object is done.

The object which I am adding is getting saved into the database immediately after the button click. But when redirection is happening it is not getting reflected at the same time. Instead when I again load that page through the sidebar buttons (with struts action), that object which I added previously, is coming.

I am not getting why it is happening and what should I do to resolve this issue.

**UI of that page:-**

[image]

Image Shows the UI on which plus icon has the functionality to add a complete row (an object is getting added in back-end)

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="AddCategory" class="Action.GoalSheetAction" method="AddCategoryy">
    <result name="Success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">EditGoalSheet</param>
    </result>
</action>
<action name="EditGoalSheet" class="Action.GoalSheetAction" method="EditGoalSheet">
    <result name="Success">/employee/GoalSheet.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/employee/GoalSheet.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.
Wherever I was using `.equals` to equate the objects, I replaced that with `==` and the problem is solved. Also I did some modifications in my **struts.xml**.
I added `<param>` with all the redirect actions I was using.